# How to use JOIN instead of comma?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO Votes (id_post,id_user)
SELECT ?,?
    FROM Posts p, Users u
  WHERE p.id_user = :id_author
         AND u.id = $_SESSION['id']
         AND u.active = 1
  limit 1;
```

Now I want to use `JOIN` instead of `,`. But there isn't any common column between those two tables. So what should I write in `ON` clause?

---

**What I'm trying to do:**

I have three tables:

```
// Posts
+----+----------+---------------+-----------+
| id |  title   |    content    | id_author |
+----+----------+---------------+-----------+
| 1  | title1   | content1      | 1234      |
| 2  | title2   | content2      | 5678      |
+----+----------+---------------+-----------+
//                                ^ the id of post's author

// Users
+----+--------+--------+
| id |  name  | active |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | jack   | 1      |
| 2  | peter  | 0      |
| 3  | John   | 1      |
+----+--------+--------+

// Votes
+----+---------+---------+
| id | id_post | id_user |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | 32      | 1234    |
| 2  | 634     | 5678    |
| 3  | 352     | 1234    |
+----+---------+---------+
//               ^ the id of current user
```

Now I need to check two conditions before inserting a new vote into `Votes` table:

1. Is the id of author the same as what I pass as `id_author`? `Posts.id_user = :id_author` (I know I can do that by a FK, but I don't want)
2. The account of current user is active? `Users.active = 1`

**Sum Up:** I'm trying to don't let people be able to vote who are inactive *(`active = 0`)*. For example if Stackoverflow bans you, then you cannot vote to posts anymore, because you (current user) are banned. So I'm pretty sure `$_SESSION['id']` should be used in the query to determine current user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using `exists` instead of `join`:

```
INSERT INTO Votes (id_post, id_user) 
SELECT id_post, id_user FROM (SELECT ? id_post, ? id_user) a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Users
    WHERE id = ?
    AND active = 1
) AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM posts
    WHERE id_user = :id_author
)
```

Comment: This is very good .. upvote .. but incomplete (it just checks second condition). I also need to check this `p.id_user = :id_author` form `Posts` table.

Comment: Yes .. this is correct now .. now I don't know this your query is better or mine (`join` vs `exists`)

Comment: @stack try running both queries with `explain` to see the query plan :)

Comment: This query doesn't execute. There is a syntax error. Your first `SELECT` doesn't has `FROM`. I think that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You already have a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) here! This is an implicit join.

> INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of
>   a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the
>   specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is
>   joined to each and every row in the second table).

So there isn't a need for you to 'introduce' a join here.

Comment: this answer is technically correct, though I'm not sure if it's efficient. cross product makes me think it's not but `limit 1` might alleviate that? ... anyway +1 for the explanation